# Maintaining the viewport size using css

Tags: html, css

i have an image on the homepage. its aspect ratio is 16:9. so whenever the height is set as 100%, the width on non-wide monitors exceeds the regular viewport width. is there a way to not make the horizontal scrollbars appear in this case? please help. i just want to hide these extra portion of images using some css properties.
**HTML**

```
    <html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css">
</head>
<body>
<ul id="nav">
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
<div>
<img src="test.jpg"/>
<div id="ht">
<p>I'm red</p>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
margin: 0;
}
#nav {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 }
#nav li {
 width: 20%;
 float: left;
 text-align: center;
 }
#nav li a {
 line-height: 400%;
 display: block;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #F2F2F2;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(51,51,51,0.3);
 box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(51,51,51,0.3);
 }
#nav a:link, #nav a:visited {
 background-color: #071726;
 }
 #nav a:hover, #nav a:active, #nav a:focus {
 background-color: #326773;
 }
img {
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:0px;
z-index:-1;
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
}
#ht {
position: relative;
top: 100px;
left: 45px;
}
#container {
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: so you want the image to turn into a 4:3 aspect ratio on 4:3 monitors?

Comment: no, on a 4:3 monitor, the scrollbars (horizontal) should not appear.

Comment: I don't think it's your image - check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/bgEar/1/ - I just added display: inline-block; on your #ht class

Comment: nope, that din't work either. the image is from shutterstock. can i display it here?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want your image to be a background of the website. Remove it then from the DOM and add a `background` property for the body style. To define the size of the image, use `background-size` property. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SLxBF/1/) - it shows the difference between *contain* and *cover* values of the `background-size` property.

```
body {
    background: url(test.jpg) no-repeat scroll center center;
    background-size: cover;
    /* OR */
    background-size: contain;
}
```

**EDIT**:
Here's the same solution wrapped with your markup: http://jsfiddle.net/A3uKs/

Comment: no, it's not a background. i have to place multiple images underneath this image.

Comment: Ok, but you positioned the image `absolutely` anyway. So you'll need to know the rendered height of it to put some additional content below it. In this case my solution works the same.

Answer (score 0):

it's quite difficult to understand what you need without any code samples, so- please be sure to add them next time.

anyway, make sure there's a container wrapping all of the content/images, let's give it the id `cont`.

now, in css, declare:

```
#cont{overflow:hidden;}
```

hope that helps.

Comment: That will hide content that doesn't fit on the screen. Surely nobody wants this to happen!